# images, css and javascript not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

we have developed an rails project using rails 3 and mysql, it has images, css and javascript (jquery) and it is working fine in windows xp environment. 
But when i migrated the code to ubuntu, the images, css ( applies partially) and javascript (jquery) are not loading. i am running in development mode.
I have included the js and css like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-one", "ctlCalendar", "application", "jquery.treeview" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.6.2.min", "jquery.rails", "jquery.treeview"%>
```

Here the error i am getting:

```
Started GET "/images/LoginImage.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-13 01:02:04 +0900

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/LoginImage.png"): 

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)

Started GET "/Images/Back_Login.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-13 01:02:05 +0900

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/Images/Back_Login.gif"):  

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank You,
Sudhir C.N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu, and other Linux versions, have case-sensitive file names, while Windows XP doesn't.

This means while `LoginImage.png` and `loginimage.png` are the same in Windows, they are not the same in Ubuntu. That's probably the cause of your problem.

The same applies to path names – `/images` and `/Images` are completely different paths in Linux, so make sure not to mix them up.

Comment: thanks a lot, this solved the problem with css. but javascripts are not working... getting the error as: 
Started GET "/javascripts/all.js?1309252624" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-14 03:52:34 +0900 - any idea abt this?

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/all.js"):
  

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms)

Comment: Again, check the exact file names in Linux, sometimes the case gets mixed up during deployment, e.g. the file is named `all.JS` or something instead of `all.js`. Make absolutely sure that the folders and file names are all in the correct case.

Comment: Btw, you might have accidentally used `javascript_include_tag 'all'` instead of `javascript_include_tag :all`, unless you actually have a JS named `all.js`.

Comment: no, i am using as <%= javascript_include_tag :all %>, even than i am getting this error: Started GET "/javascripts/all.js?1309252624" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-14 04:40:56 +0900

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/all.js"):
  

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms). Also, there is no file with all.js.

Comment: Are you using asset caching? The feature where multiple JS files are combined into one, by using `:cache => true` in your `javascript_include_tag` methods?